# How to stop WebEngine after loading for too long?

Tags: java, web, javafx, javafx-webengine

I'm currently creating an automated bot to go into a certain website and do repetitive tasks. I'm using JavaFX and the WebEngine to do this. The problem is, this webpage sometimes takes a long time to load, and I don't necessarily need it to fully load.

I'm using a listener for the WebEngine, so that when loading is complete it will continue with it's tasks, but like I said this is an issue when sometimes it takes a couple minutes to load.

So my question is, is there some way I can stop the loading after a certain amount of time so that the listener will tell my program that loading is complete? Here is my listener:

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue, 
            Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {

        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            loaded = true;
            System.out.println("true");
            start();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up timer so i.e. after 1 minute stop loading page

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Stop loading page
  }
}, 60*1000);
```

Comment: This is tricky since I'm using a listener. The only way this would work is if I could manually set the webengines worker state to SUCCEEDED after a certain amount of time, and I've looked around and I'm not sure you can manually set the worker state.